# WDK отладка драйверов

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Здравствуйте. Не могу нормально настроить Kernel Debugger Visual Studio 2015. Как я понял из документации отладку драйверов предпочтительно проводить на другой машине. Разумеется выбор сразу же пал на виртуальную машину VirtualBox. По документации MSDN была настроена виртуальная машина, был открыт порт com1, Задан путь \.\pipe\wdbgcom1. В самой виртуальной машине были установлены Windows Debugging Tools x86, система windows 7. Запущен WinDBG, в настройках Kernel Debug, было выставлено BaudRate 115200, port com1, Pipe, Reconnect. Дальше в настройках Kernel Debugger были записаны все те же данные виртуальной машины. Сеть виртуальной машины была выставлена как сетевой мост, виртуалка получила ip адрес с роутера, вроде все готово, но вот только VisualStudio не видит ни в какую эту машину. Перепробовал уже все варианты их документации. Ничего не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать?